# youtube-dl problems, can't download private videos

Tags: download, youtube-dl

I want to download all my private videos, but I when try it I get errors. This is the command line arguments that I'm using:

```
youtube-dl -u "Username" -p "Password" https://youtube.com/watch?v=58e_io9sIjE
```

And here is the output:

```
[youtube] Downloading login page
[youtube] Logging in
[youtube] 58e_io9sIjE: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 58e_io9sIjE: Extracting video information
[youtube] 58e_io9sIjE: Downloading DASH manifest
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 380, in main
File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 370, in _real_main
File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 1346, in download
File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 624, in extract_info
File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 670, in process_ie_result
File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 1016, in process_video_result
File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 910, in _calc_headers
File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 936, in _calc_cookies
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cookielib.py", line 1324, in add_cookie_header
cookies = self._cookies_for_request(request)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cookielib.py", line 1250, in _cookies_for_request
cookies.extend(self._cookies_for_domain(domain, request))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cookielib.py", line 1239, in _cookies_for_domain
if not self._policy.return_ok(cookie, request):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cookielib.py", line 1071, in return_ok
if not fn(cookie, request):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cookielib.py", line 1097, in return_ok_secure
if cookie.secure and request.get_type() != "https":
AttributeError: '_PseudoRequest' object has no attribute 'get_type'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using the latest version, which I believe is currently `2015.01.16` ?

Comment: Im using `2015.01.25`.

Comment: Ok. I suggest you contact the maintainers of youtube-dl, because that looks like it's probably a bug in their code. See https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/#bugs and https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with some error in the newest update ( or other newer ). I used `2014.09.29.2` and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `youtube-dl --no-part`.